# Добавить тёмный фон вокруг View

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Есть ли в Android способ добавить тёмный фон вокруг layout'а, перекрывающий все, кроме статус бара, не наследуясь от Dialog? Мне нужен такой же затемненный фон, какой бывает при открытии диалогов. Создание layout-подложки тоже не подходит, потому, что в данном случае не будет перекрыт ActionBar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Cоздание layout-подложки тоже не подходит, потому, что в данном случае не будет перекрыт ActionBar.

Можно попробовать заменить ActionBar на Toolbar. Потом создаете кастомный View для диалога наследуясь от FrameLayout и указываете темный фон и атрибуты для высоты и ширины match_parent, в таком случае весь экран будет перекрыт, в том числе и Toolbar

Вот пример как можно сверстать корневой layout

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:elevation="0dp">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>

<com.example.DialogView
    android:id="@+id/dialog_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
```

Comment: жду что кто-то предложит более правильное решение, но на данный момент то, что вы предложили, это лучшее. Спасибо:)